# Map key value array to value array

Tags: coffeescript

I have an array of values in Coffeescript such that:

```
arr = ['key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3]
```

I want to transform this array into an array of just values. Basically,

```
arr.map (iter) -> iter.value  # arr => [1,2,3]

=> []
```

I've attempted several permutations of this, but I just keep getting back an empty array. Any tips?

Comment: No, you don't have an array of such values. Arrays doesn't contain key-value pairs. What *do* you have?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `arr = {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}`?

Comment: Why can't this just be an object literal?

Comment: @Guffa: That is a perfectly valid *CoffeeScript* array.

Comment: @Guffa I have a console.log that says otherwise. Perhaps Array is not the best term to use. The correct term would be a map?

Comment: Try to be more clear on your question. A lot of people are not realizing you are dealing with CoffeeScript.

Comment: @YuriAlbuquerque: Can people not read the tags? Or not notice the `(iter) ->`?

Comment: @muistooshort yes.But not being clear about the question is nice and will have better answers.

Comment: @muistooshort: The question was tagged Javascript.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a CoffeeScript question and the sample code is valid CoffeeScript

`arr = ['key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3]`

translates to the following JavaScript:

```
var arr;
arr = [
  {
    'key1': 1,
    'key2': 2,
    'key3': 3
  }
];
```

Firstly, you have to realize that

```
obj = 
  key1: 1 
  key2: 2
  key3: 3
```

is most likely what you want.

Then you can use the following code to create an array with only the values of the object.

```
arr = null
arr.push val for key, val of obj
```

**Update**

This one-liner from 'mu is too short' is even better.

```
arr = (val for key, val of obj)
```

Comment: Thank you for reading the tags. I'd probably go with `values = (v for own k,v of obj)` or `values = (v for k,v of obj)` though.

Comment: +1 He did not mention in his question it was CofeeScript until after some time which is why confusion was there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to StackOverflow. I tagged the question with CoffeeScript, and I had assumed that most people look at the tags. I unfortunately included JavaScript.

Comment: I got to the question through the CoffeeScript tag that's how I knew, but there are a lot more people that answer JavaScript-tagged questions so I can understand the confusion.

Comment: @muistooshort I tried a comprehension before, but my syntax was wrong. I had better read the documentation a little better. Thank you for a CoffeeScript solution.

Comment: @Zintinio: The comprehension solution is a little fiddly due to the precedence of assignment (`=`).